# Is there a good algorithm to compress a CSV of numbers while keeping predictability?

Tags: algorithm, search, hash, compression

Let's say I have a CSV of numbers, as in `1,321,3,51,5,...` where the amount of numbers is not unrealistically large (within 0 - 999999).

I need to search through a big database of such CSVs. Each number in that CSV is unique throughout the database. But the catch is that I need the option of using a single number from that CSV to identify the entire sequence.

For example, I have two elements in my database: `"1,2,3,4"` and `"5,6,7,8"`. Now, I need to find the element that contains the number `3`. The straightforward way of doing this is to just look into each object and see if it contains the number.

So I'm thinking, is there something like a lossless one-way hashing algorithm, that'll allow me to have a short alpha-numeric (or whatever else) that will uniquely identify if the number `3` has been used in it's construction?

Comment: Total count of numbers over all CSVs <= `10^6`?

Comment: "amount" has no meaning. Magnitude of numbers? Length of vectors? Number of rows?

Comment: "big database" is also very relative. Big for a laptop and big for Google are various orders of magnitude apart.

Answer (score 2):

A number is either present or not present in a CSV, with no duplicates.  You could reduce each CSV to a bit pattern: "1,2,3" becomes 1110000...000.  "1,2,4,6" becomes 1101010000...000, where 1 indicates the number is present and 0 that it is absent.

Depending on how sparse your CSVs are, you might be able to compress the bit patterns by eliminating long strings of zero bits. Thus "1,2,3" becomes 111+999997*0

Alternatively, you will need to think of a convenient way to store 1,000,000 bit numbers.  Perhaps some big integer package?

Comment: You don't need big integers, since you don't need to do any arithmetic on the 1,000,000 bit number. You can easily implement a bit array of any size by simply breaking the index into a word offset and a bit offset. E.g. making the bit array `a` out of 64-bit words with index `i`, you fetch the word `x = a[i >> 6]` and then you get the bit with `(x >> (i & 63)) & 1`.